# Closing Unhelpful Questions Which Have No Need of a Solution

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

The https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/4733/change-order-state question was asked, the OP eventually came back in the comments and said "problem solved. It was one inappropriate order"

IMO this should be closed because the question will not be helpful to others. There is no context for why the code the question was being asked about was not working since it was a botched order… or in other words, it's too localized to the OPs environment/data.

Trying to flag it to be closed, I noticed the 'Too Localized' option no longer exists. What banner would you suggest questions like these be marked for closure under? Do we need a new closure reason?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I chose to flag it for closure as Off Topic, after finding this option beneath the OT group of reasons: "Questions describing a problem that can't be reproduced and seemingly went away on its own (or went away when a typo was fixed) are off-topic as they are unlikely to help future readers."